# Symfony 3.4 the folder where web assets is set

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

In symfony 2.*

I put `/images` or `/js` under each bundle `Resources` folder, then

`php bin/console assets:install web`

it deploys the js and images to `web/public`

Now in Symfony 3.4

All `*.html.twig` files are under `/app/Resources/view` folder.

So,I put assets files next to it like `/app/Resource/public/js` `/app/Resource/public/images` and so on.

Is it correct?? and how can I deploy these files to `web` directly??

related article is [here](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/best_practices/web-assets.html)

I have read this page but can't find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply put them in the `public` directory.

The project-bundles no longer exist in the Symfony 4. 
Also you are no longer required to use the `assets:install` command using the new structure.

For example :

```
public/
   img/
      header.jpg
```

You can then reference this asset using the asset twig function as follows:

```
{{ asset('img/header.jpg') }}
```

Comment: I understood. This is unexpected. but it is convenient. thank you.

Comment: Not sure this is the best approach, although it is suggested in the link posted by OP. The assets would have to be stored in a non-publicly available folder (such as `assets` in Symfony 4), and once compiled they should go to `public`.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are using Symfony 3.4 (which is the old lts version).

As stated in your [article](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/best_practices/web-assets.html) :

> Store your assets in the web/ directory.

which is different with the version 4.0, where the assets would go to the `/public` directory.

When you put your assets in the `/web` directory, you can of course access them with the `{{ asset()}}` function. (for instance `{{ asset('img/my-picture.jpg') }}`)

Hope it helped.